# Проблема с регекспом в Java

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Прочитал про регекспы, решил сварганить один для проверки, является ли данная строка email-ом. Вроде как должен работать, но нет.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    System.out.println("Input a valid email address.");        
    Pattern email = Pattern.compile("([a-z[A-Z]])+@([a-z[A-Z]])+\Q.\E([a-z[A-Z]])+");       
    Matcher matcher = email.matcher(s.nextLine());
    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }else System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

На все запросы выдает Invalid.

Comment: @Phynn Чтобы код отформатировался, надо выделить его мышью и нажать на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Очень уж неправильный шаблон для email. Ясно же что под него половина всех адресов в инете не подойдёт.

Comment: Раз уж тут никто не читает предисловие, то напомню: я написал это только для проверки моего понимания работы регекспов, и не более!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\Q.\E
```

замените на:

```
\\Q.\\E
```

но в данном случае достаточно:

```
\\.
```

Comment: Спасибо; я сначала один бэкслеш писал, забыл проэкранировать).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал уже проверенный регэксп, чтобы проверку проходили реальные адреса с цифрами и доменами не только второго уровня.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я не собираюсь его использовать, я просто сделал простенький регексп, чтобы посмотреть, как они работают. Но за ответ - спасибо:) Пара вопросов по вашему ответу: зачем перед первым классом вы поставили ^, и номер два - если я не ошибаюсь, то вроде в конце должно быть так -    (\\.[a-zA-Z]){2,4}. Ну раз это проверенный регексп - то значит, что я что-то не понимаю).